# Not able to fetch data of a param on another page in Ionic using navParams

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a situation where I want to pass the value fetched from DB to another page in `Ionic`.

The problem is that the value is getting fetched and printed correctly on page 1 (`ForgotPasswordPage`) but not getting retrieved on page 2 (`SendCodePage`)

**forgot-password.ts**

```
export class ForgotPasswordPage {
  forgotPassword = {} as ForgotPasswordModel;
  phone: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private userProvider: UserProvider) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ForgotPasswordPage');
  }

  //GETS INVOKED ON BUTTON CLICK ON PAGE
  goSendCode() {
    (async () => {
      await this.getCurrentUserDetails(this.forgotPassword.email);
      //send the phone number we got above to next page
      this.navCtrl.push(SendCodePage, {phone: this.phone, firstName: "zzzz"});
    })();
  }

  getCurrentUserDetails(email: string) {
    this.userProvider.getUserByEmail(email)
      .then((currentUser: User) => {
        this.phone = currentUser.phone;
        console.log("phone: " + this.phone); //phone PRINTS FINE HERE
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(JSON.stringify(e)));
  }

}
```

**send-code.ts (This does NOT receive the phone parameter value)**

```
export class SendCodePage {

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private sms: SMS, private navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SendCodePage');
  }

  doSendCode() {
    (async () => {
      let firstName:string = this.navParams.get("firstName");
      let phone:string = this.navParams.get("phone");
      console.log("firstName: " + firstName); //PRINTS zzzz
      console.log("phone: " + phone); //PRINTS undefined 

      //generating a random 6 digit number here and sending sms
      let code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
      console.log("code: " + code)
      await this.sms.send(phone, code.toString());

      //navigate
      this.navCtrl.push(ResetPasswordPage);
    })();
  }

}
```

**Console Logs:**

```
[app-scripts] [00:35:27]  console.log: ionViewDidLoad SendCodePage
[app-scripts] [00:35:27]  console.log: phone: 1005009001
[app-scripts] [00:35:29]  console.log: firstName: zzzz
[app-scripts] [00:35:29]  console.log: phone: undefined
[app-scripts] [00:35:29]  console.log: code: 41676
[app-scripts] [00:35:30]  console.log: ionViewDidLoad ResetPasswordPage
```

Comment: In your second page doSendCode() method is not calling while page enter you need to call that method

Answer (score 0):

```
goSendCode() {
    (async () => {
      await this.getCurrentUserDetails(this.forgotPassword.email);
    })();
  }



getCurrentUserDetails(email: string) {
    this.userProvider.getUserByEmail(email)
      .then((currentUser: User) => {
        this.phone = currentUser.phone;
        console.log("phone: " + this.phone); //phone PRINTS FINE HERE
          **//send the phone number we got above to next page
          this.navCtrl.push(SendCodePage, {phone: this.phone, firstName: "zzzz"});**
      })
      .catch(e => console.error(JSON.stringify(e)));
  }
```

Please add the `this.navCtrl.push(SendCodePage, {phone: this.phone, firstName: "zzzz"})` to the success call back of the `getCurrentUserDetails()` method. Because the `push(<>)` may invoke before the completion of the `api` call.

One more thing, from where you are invoking the method `doSendCode()` in your second page?

Please check and let me know the result.

Comment: This is what I see when  I run the app: `app-scripts] [02:12:49]  console.error:
[app-scripts]             {"__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}`

Comment: After following my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small misuse of async await in your code.
async await are there to simplify your code and get rid off then and catch nesting code. therefore your code should look like :

```
async goSendCode() {
    const user = await this.getCurrentUserDetails(this.forgotPassword.email);
    this.navCtrl.push(SendCodePage, {phone: user.phone, firstName: user.firstName});
  }

getCurrentUserDetails(email: string) {
    return this.userProvider.getUserByEmail(email)
}
```

as you can see above, this code looks much readable.

From your SendCodePage you need to call that method sendCode from ionViewDidLoad like so :

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SendCodePage');
    this.doSendCode();
}
```

Again, you don't need to enclosure your async await in an anonymous function as it only adds confusion :

```
async doSendCode() {
      let firstName:string = this.navParams.get("firstName");
      let phone:string = this.navParams.get("phone");
      console.log("firstName: " + firstName); //PRINTS zzzz
      console.log("phone: " + phone); //PRINTS undefined 

      //generating a random 6 digit number here and sending sms
      let code = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
      console.log("code: " + code)
      await this.sms.send(phone, code.toString());
      //navigate
      this.navCtrl.push(ResetPasswordPage);
  }
```